# background task does not emit

Tags: python-3.x, flask, socket.io

There are many tutorials available for Flask and SocketIO, I could not find any for a simple threaded approach that I understood. But I did read and followed many of them. 
I'd like to show my Python application on a web page using websockets so it's kind-of real-time monitoring. This is me trying to understand how to implement this.

The code I currently have is working for except the emit part. There does not seem to be any transfer of data. I'd like to know why.

The `socket.on('tingeling' ...` is not being triggered.

My Python code, mostly taken from https://codeburst.io/building-your-first-chat-application-using-flask-in-7-minutes-f98de4adfa5d

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = ''
socketio = SocketIO(app)
thread = None

def counter():
    print("counter ding")
    counting = 0

    while True:
        counting += 1
        socketio.sleep(2)
        socketio.emit('tingeling', counting, namespace='')
        print(f"Counter: {counting}")

@app.route('/')
def sessions():
    print('route')
    return render_template('index.html')

@socketio.on('my event')
def connected(data):
    print('my event')

@socketio.on('connect')
def starten():
    print("connect")
    socketio.emit('tingeling', 'start')
    global thread
    if thread is None:
        print('thread ding')
        thread = socketio.start_background_task(target=counter())
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, debug=True)
```

And my HTML template:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>fristi</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <h3 style='color: #ccc;font-size: 30px;'>waiting</h3>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.7.3/socket.io.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);
      console.log('doet iets')

      socket.on( 'connect', function() {
          socket.emit( 'my event', {
              data: 'User Connected'
          })
      })

      socket.on('tingeling', function(msg) {
        console.log('iets komt binnen')
        console.log(msg)
      })

    </script>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

My error is on the line: `thread = socketio.start_background_task(target=counter())`

There I reference the function to run as a background task but I use the notation with `()` and that is not allowed because is runs the function and does not provide the `start_background_task` with a reference to this function.